# Calling Powershell command using C#

Tags: powershell, c#-4.0, process

I've tried to execute this PowerShell command using C#, and wait for the output, which is a list of SharePoint sites on my domain!! the PowerShell itself works fine, but using C# process to call it, doesn't wait for the output!!!!
any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

//Command

```
string cmd = @"[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SharePoint') >        $null  
$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local 
$websvcs = $farm.Services | where -FilterScript {$_.GetType() -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]} 
$webapps = @() 
foreach ($websvc in $websvcs) {  
        foreach ($webapp in $websvc.WebApplications) {  
                foreach ($site in $webapp.Sites) { 
                $site.URL  
                } 
        } 
} ";
```

//C# Process!

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", cmd);
        proc.Start();
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.WaitForExit();
        string output = "";
        while (!proc.HasExited)
        {
            output += proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.HasExited` will always be `true` once `proc.WaitForExit()` has completed, therefore your `while` loop will never be entered and `output` will have its initial value.  You don't need the loop and can instead just read the output once the process has exited:

```
proc.WaitForExit();
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I assume you have a specific reason for wanting to execute PowerShell code in a child process.  Otherwise, a better way to go would be the answer from @Keith Hill or just translate your PowerShell code to C# and query the data directly from your application.  After adding a reference to the `System.Management.Automation` assembly and some `using` statements for the `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Linq` namespaces, a direct translation would be something like...

```
var farm = Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Local;
var websvcs = farm.Services.OfType<Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService>();
var siteUrls = new List<string>();

foreach (var websvc in websvcs)
    foreach (var webapp in websvc.WebApplications)
        foreach (var site in webapp.Sites)
            siteUrls.Add(site.Url);
```

...and a more LINQified approach could be...

```
var farm = Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Local;
var websvcs = farm.Services.OfType<Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService>();
var siteUrls = websvcs
    .SelectMany(websvc => websvc.WebApplications)
    .SelectMany(webapp => webapp.Sites)
    .Select(site => site.Url);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry for my little powershell experience:
this is the Exception I'm getting,

Exception: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.\nAt line:3 char:50\n+ $websvcs = $farm.Services | where -FilterScript {$_.GetType() -eq

Answer (score 0):

I would use the PowerShell automation engine for this. In your C# project, reference the assembly `System.Management.Automation.dll` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0`. Then in your code try this:

```
string cmd = "your commands";
string output = "";
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript(cmd);
    var results = ps.Invoke();
    foreach (var result in results) 
    {
        output += result.ToString();
    }
}
```

If you only get type names in your output, change this line:

```
$site.URL
```

to:

```
$site.URL | Out-String
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry for my little powershell experience:
this is the Exception I'm getting,

Exception: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.\nAt line:3 char:50\n+ $websvcs = $farm.Services | where -FilterScript {$_.GetType() -eq

Answer (score 0):

```
var farm = Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Local;
        var websvcs = farm.Services.OfType<Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService>();
        var siteUrls = websvcs
            .SelectMany(websvc => websvc.WebApplications)
            .SelectMany(webapp => webapp.Sites)
            .Select(site => site.Url);

        foreach (var i in siteUrls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
```